How can you scale without distorting the shape?
I need to scale it proportionately.  I drew the cyan head bar and group it with the deep ash bar. So they both are in a group. but when I scale it they get distorted. How can I scale it without distorting it? I untick the stroke scale option from scale properties. (attached).



Scale in what way? Often easier to grab and move anchors if you want non-proportional scaling.

at last I cud attach the Gif. kindly check. I wanna scale it from left to right but want to keep the head bar in same figure like it was in the beginning.

Yeah.. drag anchors, not bounding box handles.

Thank you So much.

The handle dragging for Illustrator's Bounding Box (or Free transform Tool) do not really accommodate any type of dynamic measuring of elements. While it is possible the get rounded corners to scale when you enlarge or reduce an object uniformly. When you are performing non-uniform scaling, no handle dragging will keep things proportional.
If you want to change the width or height of an object or collection of objects, it is much more advisable to use the Direct Selection Tool and select specific anchor points then move those anchors to accommodate a new width/height.
In short, "dragging a handle" to alter only a width or height of an object(s) will never result in proportional scaling. You need to move the anchors rather than handle-dragging.

Thank you so much.

While you are mostly right there is a feature in illustrator to do this its called 9 slice and its a option for symbols. Its generally mostly useless but its exactly the thing for this use case.

9-slice works fantastic if enlarging reducing.. and can at times work if non0uniform scaling. But.. for matters like this, I don't think it worth trying to rely on that.

@Scott no it works fine, just dont like the loss of snapping anchors that comes with symbols.

If thats a group or compounded shape, it always does that when scaling. You would have to ungroup and control the shapes manually. Or enter ouline mode via CTRL+Y and drag the anchors at a larger zoom level.

Thank you so much.

You can do this with symbols that have 9 slice scaling turned on. What you do is:

Draw your shape
Create a symbol of it, remeber to enable 9 slice scaling
Nucleoside on symbol and adjust the 9 slice guides so you have the things that you want to stray same not in the center slice.

And now the scale works the way you want, just remember to do a nonuniform scale.
Here is a youtube video (not mine no affiliation) that's shows the same process.

I dont tend to use this i do what @Scott does. The reason being symbols dont snap nearly to anything. So they are mostly useless for making things. So the bother or marquee selecting with snapping is better than having scale handles do this. If adobe ever make symbols snap intelligently with their content this becomes a viable tool.

Thank you so much.
